# Understanding SLAVEOF command to change redis slave to master

Tags: redis, failover, master-slave

I want to change my redis slave to master so I read about [SLAVEOF](https://redis.io/commands/slaveof). But I don't understand this line:

"The form SLAVEOF NO ONE will stop replication, turning the server into a 
MASTER, but will not discard the replication"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the following edit will help you understand:

> The form SLAVEOF NO ONE will stop replication, turning the server into a MASTER, but will not discard the **replicated data**

Answer (score 0):

That is now obsolete. Instead use `REPLICAOF NO ONE`. More infor can be found in here: https://redis.io/commands/replicaof/